# How to stop service when the app get closed android

Tags: android, service

Can any one tell me how to stop the service when the app get closed.
In my project the service is still running in background even though the application got closed.Here i've given my sources for reference.

Suggestions please.

Thanks for your precious time!..

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent
            .getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // Start service every 20 seconds
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            10* 1000, pintent);

}


}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {


String result_data = "";

public MyService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
//  Toast.makeText(this, "The new Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // For time consuming an long tasks you can launch a new thread here...
    Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Authentication_Class task = new Authentication_Class();
    task.execute();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public class Authentication_Class extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Call_service();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }

    private void Call_service() throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    String URL          =   "";
    String METHOD_NAME  =   "";
    String NAMESPACE    =   "";
    String SOAPACTION   =   "";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    // Add parameters if available 

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL,15000);
    try {

        httpTransportSE.call(SOAPACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        result_data = String.valueOf(result);
        System.out.println(">>-- RESPONSE    :    " +result_data);


    } 

    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your onDestroy() method in the activity where you are finishing your last activity like this:

```
 @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {

            super.onDestroy();
            AppLog.Log(TAG, "On destroy");
            stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService .class));

}
```

Comment: i've tried your suggestion, but its still running in background!

Comment: 1 doubt, if i use the above onDestroy() in the same MainActivity.java, then what will happen?

Comment: put that code in the activity in which you want to stop service and if you are putting that in MainActivity.java then it will stopservice when activity got finished.

Comment: Can you tell me in what situation the method onDestroy() will be called?

Comment: On the above source,see MainActivity.java, im starting the service on oncreate() method, so that it is still running. But i dont know how to stop that service.do you have any idea?

Comment: use alarm.cancel(pIntent);